# Determine minimum and maximum number of leaves on a complete tree

Tags: trees, binary-trees

I want to determine the minimum and maximum number of leaves of a complete tree(not necessarily a binary tree) of height $h$.
I already know how to find minimum($h+1$) and maximum($2^{h+1}-1$) number of **nodes** from the height, but what about *leaves*? Is there a way to determine them knowing nothing but height of the tree?

Comment: What do you means with complete? Is the number of children specified (you only mentioned not binary)?

Comment: @narekBojikian _In a complete binary tree every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible._. the number of children is not specified but you can assume a binary tree.

Comment: But what do you mean then with "not necessarily a binary"

Comment: That it can be any kind of m-ary tree, i.e. a ternary tree, a binary tree or anything else. The number of children is the irrelevant part of this problem.

Comment: Let's recall the definitions. In an $m$-ary tree, each node has at most $m$ children. In a complete $m$-ary tree, each node (except the leaves) has $m$ children, the leaves have 0 children. In other words, asking what number of children is is very relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> Try the case $h=1$.  What's the minimum?  What's the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

For a given **height (h)** in m-ary tree, you can calculate first the max/main number of nodes and then calculate the leaves according to each situation:

1. To calculate the **max/min** number of nodes in m-ary tree use the following equations:

**Maximum number of nodes: $\frac{m^{h+1}-1} {m-1}$**

**Minimum number of nodes: $(mh)+1$**

2. Now you would use the following equation to calculate and find the **internal nodes (I)** from **vertices (n)**

**$I = \frac{n-1} m$**

3. You would have **Internal nodes (I)**, and **vertices (n)**. So finally you would use the following equation to find the **leaves (L)**

**$L = n - I$**